# Running Flask and Postman on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, postman, raspberry-pi3, flask-restful

I'm running a flask server on my Raspberry Pi just a simple one to test the POST or GET request but Postman "Could not send request". But when I try to access the link via the browser, it displays the request.

I'm accessing Raspberry Pi via SSH and using VNC Viewer.)

I'm confused. Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I'm running flask on the raspberry pi itself and using a browser on the rasp, I'm accessing Postman.

Below are a few images so that you get an idea what I'm doing.

[image: Simple GET request code]

[image: Postman]

[image: Request in browser]

[image: Console]

Comment: to be clear: you run the postman application and the flask server on the same machine (raspberry pi)? If yes did you check if the networkport you run the server on is receiving/sending correctly (no blocking)

Comment: @4lexKidd Yes they are running on the raspberry pi itself. How do I check this? By default the port is 5000. Even on the port 5000 which is development port, I still get the same result

Comment: Nevermind, if you can reach the server on the browser then your port must be reaciving/sending properly. Only possibilty for a check would be your postman configuration or your server configuration. Try to reach another service or other open-source api with it(for example any open weather api). If this works then it might be an issue about your postman not able to reach your local host. If postman can not reach other api as well then your postman is probably mis-configured.

Comment: @4lexKidd I tried using a dummy api and everything seems to work well. It is retrieving data as it should be.

Comment: when you send request via postman, what do you see in the console log, bottom bar looking like ```[] Console```

Comment: @djmonki I updated the post .. I added the console

Comment: Added possible solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following 2 stages:

1. On the GET Request, select the '**Authorization**' tab. Select '**No Auth**' from the '**Type**' drop down list
2. Select the cog icon at the top of the Postman application -> Choose '**Settings**' -> '**General**' tab -> '**Request**' column -> Set '**SSL certificate verification**' to '**OFF**'